# Weird CSS in Internet Explorer (Concerning margins, I believe)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a weird rendering issue in IE concerning an inline unordered list. What I'm trying to do is make a visualizer for the lifespan of a project, but whenever I try to add in any text in my `<p>` object designed to hold a time period, it shifts the whole `<li>` element down, but **only in Internet Explorer.**

Please, take a gander at this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/xny1zv3j/

I'm okay with the name and position (ex: 'John' and 'Project Lead' being pulled down - that's not an issue for me. But in IE, and IE only, it seems as if the entire list element is pulled down. When the `<p>` element is empty, it's simply ignored, and is fine in all browsers, but when it has content, IE freaks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply add `vertical-align: top` to your `.li` class.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are shooting for? https://jsfiddle.net/xny1zv3j/3/

HTML

```
<div class="container body-content">
<div class="container" id="main-container">
        <ul class="timeline">
            <li class="li" >
                <div class="timestamp">
                    <div class="author">John</div>
                    <div class="date">Project Lead</div>
                </div>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="time-period">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Created Project</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li" >
                <div class="timestamp">
                    <div class="author">Jenny</div>
                    <div class="date">Programmer</div>
                </div>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="time-period">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Built Project</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li" >
                <div class="timestamp">
                    <div class="author">Jeremy</div>
                    <div class="date">Marketing</div>
                </div>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="time-period">
                        <p>2 yrs</p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Advertised Project</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li" >
                <div class="timestamp">
                    <div class="author">Jack</div>
                    <div class="date">Sales</div>
                </div>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="time-period">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Sold Project</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li" >
                <div class="timestamp">
                    <div class="author">Jebeddiah</div>
                    <div class="date">IT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="status">
                    <div class="time-period">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Defended Project</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .timeline {
   text-align: left;
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom:-23px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
 }

 .li {
   width: 150px;
   display: inline-block; 
   }

 .timestamp {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   padding: 0px;
   font-weight: 100;
   display: block;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .status {
   padding-top: 10px;
   position: relative;
   transition: all 200ms ease-in;
   white-space: normal;

 }
   .status h4 {
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     padding-bottom: 3px;
   }
   .time-period {
     display: inline;
     text-align: center; }

     .time-period p {
      /* margin: -30px 0px 20px;*/
     }

     .time-period p:empty {
         display:inline-block;
     }
```